# Hide address bar in Android Chrome automatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I am opening a simple web on Chrome for Android. I need to hide the address bar without user interaction. I tried the `window.scrollTo(0, 1)` method, which isn't working. I think the newer browsers don't support it, but I installed Chrome 36 and it still didn't work there. I know that is a hack. But the whole web page I am displaying is a hack and I can't do anything about that. I can't use other browsers. I can't use fullscreen, because that requires user interaction. I can't make it into progressive app.

As soon as I manually scroll, the address bar disappears. So I thought maybe I could somehow simulate that. But I am lost with ideas.

Comment: It may only hide when actual user interaction causes a scroll. Why do you need forcing the address bar to hide though? Is that small real estate really that important from the second the page loads?

Comment: It's used to display data. And the request was to make it display just the data without any other elements as the address bar. Also there won't be any users interacting with it.

Comment: I think user7984880 is right. If hiding the address bar was possible, phishing sites could auto hide the address bar to conceal the fact that you're not actually on the website that you think you are. That would be very dangerous

Comment: You could ask your user to pin the app to the Home Screen and then, at a launch as webapp, make the address bar disappear. I'm sure that's possible (as stackedit.io is doing it), just don't know how.

Comment: Would it be possible to enable some Chrome flag or something similiar? I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I tried to pin it down, but I couldn't make the option appear in Chrome. Maybe it's because of my Android version (4.4). Also I have to run the Chrome automatically on the Android startup and I don't think you can do that with the pinned app.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you would be able to hide it since that would be a risk to the security of the Android user.

Comment: I can't comment yet, but I am quite sure you can't for that reason alone